# VMWare FT Logging

Tags: vmware, esxi, fault-tolerance

I am newbie to VMWare. So while working on the standard switch i came across FTLogging. I did not found any best source. So can some one please expline where we use FTLogging and under which conditions we need to use FTLooging. What is the use of configuring FTLooging?How it works?  Thanks in advance

Comment: +ashok Please find the below information that might useful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use VMware FT, there are two networking requirements that must be met. The first of these requirements is a vMotion network to be used by ESXi hosts in the cluster. vMotion is required, because the secondary VM is initially created by a vMotion of the primary VM to a different ESXi host in the cluster. Because of this design, it is also recommended to have separate 1GbE NICs for vMotion and fault tolerance logging traffic.
The fault tolerance logging traffic is the second network requirement for VMware FT. This is also a VMkernel connection type that is used to move all nondeterministic events from the primary VM to the secondary VM. Nondeterministic events include network and user input, asynchronous disk I/O, and CPU timer events. This is the connection that is used to keep the primary and secondary virtual machines in lockstep.
In Exercise 8.13, I will create a baseline networking setup that will include both vMotion and fault tolerance logging networking. This exercise will use a standard vSwitch and will require two available NICs in each ESXi host in the cluster. If you already have a vSwitch created for vMotion, you can omit the sections of this exercise that pertain to creating the vMotion network.

Comment: +MAK Thanks for the information. This is what i am looking for. Can you please tell me from where you got this concept

Comment: +ashok This is from safaribooks online